# how to store view template into mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, templates, view

I want to create and save view template files (ready-made page templates with different page structure and css) into mysql database.

Each template files will have the same records rendered, only the layout will be different.

Admin can select necessary available template from database while configuring  and data will be rendered into that template at regular user's interface.

I have thought of creating files as:

```
views/templates/template1.php
views/templates/template2.php
views/templates/template3.php...
```

in my project view directory, and manually insert these template names into database as:

```
template_id  |  template_file_name  |  status
---------------------------------------------
1            |  template1.php       |  1
2            |  template2.php       |  1
3            |  template3.php       |  1
4            |  template4.php       |  0
```

so that say, for a question/answer test or something, admin can select from anyone of these available templates.

When user loads a particular question/answer set, q/a records will be loaded into that template:

question_answer.php:

```
<?php include($row['template_file_name']); ?>
```

or something like this.

Is it the right way or is there any other smarter way to do this?

I hope I am making my problem clear.

Comment: Broad design questions like this are not really appropriate for [so]. If you have code that tries to implement it, and it doesn't work, we can help you fix it.

Comment: just trying to be guided. that's all..

Comment: I understand what you want, but you're asking for it in the wrong place. [so] is for questions about specific code, not general design advice. It should be possible to write an objectively correct answer that you can accept. What you're asking for would elicit opinions about different ways to design your application.

Comment: Your decision to use template name and store they in db is good.